# Redirecionar pagina através de um select php

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como faço para redirecionar uma página através de um `select`, tendo em vista que eu preciso do `value` do mesmo.

```
<select name="setor" id="setor">
  <option value="">Selecionar Setor</option>
  <option value="age">Agenciamento</option>
  <option value="exp">Exportação</option>
  <option value="imp">Importação</option>
  <option value="int">Internação</option>
  <option value="pro">Processos</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Vai passar o valor por POST ou GET?

Comment: via post, @MárcioEric.

Comment: E porque não usar o método tradicional?  <form method="post" .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá para fazer utilizando *JavaScript*.

Cria uma função no `onChange` passando como parâmetro o valor escolhido.

Ele vai chamar a função e mandar para uma página com o devido valor como parâmetro.

```js
function redirectPage(v) {
    document.location.href = 'pagina.php?param='+v;    
}
```

```html
<select name="setor" id="setor" onChange="redirectPage(this.value)">
  <option value="">Selecionar Setor</option>
  <option value="age">Agenciamento</option>
  <option value="exp">Exportação</option>
  <option value="imp">Importação</option>
  <option value="int">Internação</option>
  <option value="pro">Processos</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Como faço para enviar a informação via POST, @DiegoSouza?!

Comment: Faz um ajax dentro dessa função.